# Pandas рассчет mode() на скользящем окне

Tags: python, pandas, оптимизация, анализ-данных

Как быстро посчитать моду на скользящем окне в pandas?

Средствами pandas выдает ошибку:

```
Dts[fnc].rolling(1000).mode()
```

> AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'mode'

Через apply и lambda очень долго:

```
%timeit Dts[fnc].rolling(1000).apply(lambda x: stats.mode(x)[0])
```

Результат:

> 5.67 s ± 277 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: Почему вы используете 'stats.mode(x)[0]' вместо 'x.mode()' ?

Comment: @MaxU Потому что плохо знаю возможности api panas :=) Документация с примерами не дают ответов на многие вопросы, но есть MaxU . Как всегда огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться "родным" Pandas методом [Series.mode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html):

```
Dts[fnc].rolling(1000).apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```